# Wrap all methods and properties with regions with Visual Studio or Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-generation

Anyone know of a quick way to individually wrap all properties and methods of a class with a region? The region name needs to be the signature of the method or property.

The ability to create these with a simple keystroke combination in Visual Studio or with Resharper would make a huge time saver.

**Example**

```
#region public IEmrApplianceProcessor GetProcessor(Guid emrApplianceKey)

public IEmrApplianceProcessor GetProcessor(Guid emrApplianceKey)
{   
    ...
}

#endregion

#region private readonly IEmrAppliances _emrAppliances

private readonly IEmrAppliances _emrAppliances = null;

#endregion

#region private readonly ILog _log

private readonly ILog _log = null;

#endregion
```

Thanks for any/all help!

Comment: Just curious but why would you want to do that? If you just collapsed your code CTRL + M, O would present the code in a similar fashion.

Comment: I think regions are nice for collapsing large blocks. But imho it should never be used for... _here are the properties_ or _constructors_ etc. It should explain what it does, not what it is.

Comment: @CraigSelbert Unfortunately this is an inherited coding style that we must stick with.

Comment: I'm going to agree with @Craig and @Jeroen; seems to be alot of micromanagement. Regions IMHO should be used for collapsing code that normally would not be, be it within a method or enveloping multiple methods. _Property & Constructor_ definitions/comments would be best done with XML comment syntax, especially when multiple methods are wrapped

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Agreed completely, this format is not by choice and gets really frustrating when the region doesn't match the signature.

Comment: @MadMyche Totally agree that this is not the best use of regions. But, if this is a required coding standard we must stick to, the ability to auto generate all of these regions for a class would make this much less of an issue.

Comment: Time for a new job :)

Comment: LOL @Matthias in the event my coworkers find this question; That's ludacris, I love my job ;)

Comment: Just joking! :D

Answer (score 3):

This won't do all your properties and methods automatically, but it might save time. Highlight what you want enclosed in a region. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>#</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> to quickly wrap a region around you code using snippets.

Comment: This is very useful but wish there was a way to peek at the method and/or property signature and auto populate the region name.